# El Calafate, Argentina

Tags: argentina

We're about to travel and be in El Calafate, Argentina in the end of November, beginning of December so we're looking at flights. Have noticed that there's no flights Nov 27 - Dec 2 from El Calafate to Buenos Aires and it becomes a lot pricier the days before this. Do anyone knows what happens there during these days? I can't find anything about any special events on the web.

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Are you sure your real question is not *How do I get there at a reasonable price?* If so, please edit your question and add some prices. If I'm wrong, leave it.

Comment: @user2069136 Where is your departure point?

Comment: Sorry, trying to get to Buenos Aires from El Calafate these dates. Edited now!